# How do you not allow texture overlay to affect stroke but still text fill?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, texture, lettering

[image]

I want to achieve a strong eroded photocopy effect for the fill of my lettering but maintain a strong dark stroke unaffected by the overlay textures such as the image provided.

Comment: If you *don't* want something affected there are 2 options.... 1) separate elements or 2) mask elements.

Answer (score -1):

If the stroke is a Layer style and the overlay texture is another layer in clipping mask, it should work (the cliping mask only affect the fill and not the style).